# How to enable duplicating questions in Google form by the user who is filling it

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I have a Google form with two parts. The first part is personal details (name, phone etc.). The second part is other information from the users.

For my real needs, each part contains several questions, but for the example, let's say that the first part is "full name", and the second is "A book I recommend".

Some users may want to recommend more than one book, but obviously their full name is the same for all recommendations.

So I'm looking for an option to "duplicate" the second part when needed. So the user will first fill in his name. Then he'll fill in a name of a book, and will be able to click on a button for adding another recommended book, and after adding all books, submit them all at once.

In the spreadsheet behind the form, each form will possibly create more than one line, a line for each recommended book, and the "full name" column will be the same for all the lines.

Is there such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I have done to accomplish this(sort of) is to make a certain number of identical questions.  It could be 5 or 10 or whatever you see the max number being.  Then I add a question at the end of each of those that asks if the person would like to add another.

So, in your case, you would have Book 1, Book 2, and Book 3.  All are separate sections in the form.  The person fills out Book 1 recommendation and says yes to adding another.  They get routed to Book 2 section.  They only have 2 recommendations so they answer no to adding another.  They then get routed to the final section in the form which just contains a submit button.

I wish the ability to just add another question like you are asking for existed but until Google adds something like that, this should get the job done for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that such option does not exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a radio box with 'Go to Page based on answer' checked. Then a second page with the duplicate question. Once they answer the second question, they could be routed back to Page One or the form could be complete.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this option, thanks! However, this solution is quite limited, because if the user wants to recommend 3 books, or more, he can't.